# Is there an issue with orientation when going into the background on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, orientation

I have a strange issue on iPAD. The app currently only supports Landscape.

However, when the user rotates the device to portrait and returns to the app, the app returns as portrait.

Another detail, the view has been presented modally before going into the background.

I am not sure if this is an iOS issue? or is there something I need to handle to catch orientation changes?

Comment: how are you restricting app in landscape mode?

Comment: Through the info.plist with the Supported interface orientations (iPad) property